# A Missing Symbol for This Logo

Tags: visual

[image: a logo with a missing symbol]

> What symbol should I put in the center to complete this logo?

Comment: **XLII**; aka: forty-two.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

> [image: symbol]

Because:

> If you rotate it so that each sentence is at the top, you get:
>
>  [image: explanations]

...or in animated form:

> [image: animated explanations]

Comment: rot13(Jbhyq jbex orggre nf n tvs jvgu gur flzoby ebgngvat.) =)

Comment: @jpmc26 - I actually did that at first, but it felt a bit confusing... When I'm back at my PC, I might have another go.

Comment: Yep, exactly like that!

Comment: To be fair, I prefer the non-animated version; it allows the slower ones like me to study it at our own pace, and the smarter ones to not have to wait. :)

Comment: @jpmc26 - as requested (see edit) :)